# User profile service fails

Tags: windows, multi-boot, windows-8.1

I have Windows 7 and 3 drives on my HDD. The second drive is D:\, and there are some files in that. I decided to install 8.1 Enterprise so I installed it in dual boot manner beside 7 and in D:\ drive which as I said was not empty and when installing 8.1, I didn't format the D:. I installed 8.1 successfully in D:\ and it was working fine. 
One time which I came up with 7, I thought I should arrange the 8.1 folders in D: to be separated from the other non-8.1 folders, so I created a new folder named it "Windows 8.1" and cut all 8.1 folders and pasted them into that new folder. Now my D: drive was arranged. When I restart the PC, I selected the 8.1 to start with, but it didn't come up like before and instead, it shows now a blue screen (not the blue screen of death!) and the time is shown in left-down corner of it. When I click the screen this message appears: 
The User Profile Service service Failed the sign-in. 
User Profile can not be loaded.

I know two things: 
1- The problem is to do with that cutting and pasting the 8.1 folders to be arranged. And
2- If I reinstall the 8.1, the problem will be solved (but if I don't do that cutting and pasting again!)

Is there any simpler way to solve the issue and have the two OSs with each other?

Answer (score 0):

Lol you can't just simply move core Windows files. Think about all the references to those file locations in the registry etc. Why didn't you just seperate the existing, non-windows related files, from your windows installation?

The only possible solution is re-arranging the Windows files and folers back to the locations where they used to be in.

Comment: I try to do that but I scare I finally have to reinstall it again! Thanks.